# A base for a topology

Tags: general-topology

I am quite confused about what exactly a base for a topology is.  I understand it when the topologies are pretty simple, but things start to get a little confusing for me after awhile.

For example, this makes sense to me:

The topology $\big\{\varnothing,\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\big\}$ on the set $\{a,b\}$ has the following bases:

1. $\big\{\varnothing,\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\big\}$
2. $\big\{\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\big\}$
3. $\big\{\varnothing,\{a\},\{b\}\big\}$
4. $\big\{\{a\},\{b\}\big\}$

Things get extremely confusing when things get a bit beyond that...

I apologize guys and gals, but these explanations are really not helping me too much :/
Maybe if someone explains a few questions in my book may help a bit:

(a)  Explain why this is not a basis for a topology on $\mathbb R$:  $\{(n,n+1):n \in \mathbb Z\}$

So what exactly is a topology on R?  Maybe this will help answer my questions as well...

Comment: Any open set can be obtained taking arbitrary union of finite intersection of basis elements.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space.  A base $\mathcal{B}$ for a topology is a collectioin of open subsets of $X$ so that for any open subset $G$ of $X$ and any $x\in G$ there is some $B\in \mathcal{B}$ so that $x\in B \subseteq G$.

Here is an example. Let $(M, d)$ be am metric space. The open balls in $M$ form a basis for the open subsets of $M$.  In fact, the open balls of radius $1/n$ for some positive integer $n$ form a basis.

Comment: It would be nice if you mention $\tau$ on your definition.

Comment: Thats the definition we are given in my book, but that really doesn't clear much up for me.

For example, 

{(a,b):a,b belong to Q} is a basis for the usual topology on R.

That makes no sense to me....

Comment: It asserts that every open set is a union of elements of $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: I'd like to add that I have no idea what a metric space is and we haven't been taught it yet either.

Answer (score 1):

Any collection $B$ of subsets of a given set $X$ generate a topology on $X$. This is done by first taking all finite intersections of members in $B$ (this is then obviously closed under finite intersections) and then taking all possible unions of such finite intersections (this will obviously be closed under arbitrary unions, and because distributivity of intersection and union, it is also still closed under finite intersections). The resulting collection is thus a topology. It is the smallest topology on $X$ in which all members of $B$ are open sets. $B$ is then called a subbasis for the topology it generates. If $B$ is such that already the union of arbitrary many elements in it is a topology, then it is called a basis.

The thing is that starting with relatively easy to understand collections $B$ (whether bases of subbases), this process typically yields so many new open sets that it is hard to figure out what exactly they are. This is so because we take arbitrary unions of members of the set, and there are (potentially) many such arbitrary unions. But this is precisely where bases are good for. It is typically very hard to describe a topology in detail simply because you have to describe all the open sets, and there are lots of those. But, if you can identity a basis (or subbasis) which is easy to understand, then you can just say: "take the topology it generates" and you can still access it via the basis. For instance, you can check for continuity of a function using bases rather than the entire topology they generate.

In a sense, this is a bit similar to what happens with bases in vector spaces. For instance, $\mathbb R^n$ is a large vector spaces, its cardinality is $c$ (uncountable!). But, its dimension is $n$ and thus there exist $n$ vectors that uniquely span all of $R^n$. So, only $n$ vectors suffice to access all of $\mathbb R^n$. Similarly, the standard topology on $\mathbb R$ has as a basis the collection of all open intervals. In fact, this is basically the definition of the standard topology: The standard topology on $\mathbb R$ is the topology generated by the open intervals. The open intervals form a lovely basis since we know very well what open intervals are. However, open sets are much subtler and they can be very complicated, with no simple characterization for them.

Answer (score 0):

I think that understanding a less contrived example is more illuminating. $\mathbb{R}^2$ in its euclidean topology has as a basis all open balls. There are lots of open sets that aren't open balls, for example open squares, but each open set is a union of open balls.

So, try to prove that another basis for the euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is open squares! Then you'll be on the road to understanding what bases are about.

Comment: That really doesn't clarify much for me or help.  Just made it a bit more confusing :/

Comment: Metric spaces are simpler and more accessible than general topological spaces.  Here is a good place to spend a few bucks:  http://www.amazon.com/Theory-Metric-Spaces-Chelsea-Publishing/dp/0821826948/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1383095012&sr=8-3&keywords=metric+spaces

Answer (score 0):

An example would be the collection $\mathcal{B}$ of all open intervals $(a,b)$ that is a basis for the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$. It is not hard to see that for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ there is an element $A$ of $\mathcal{B}$ such that $x\in A\subseteq U$ for each open set $U$. If $x\in A_1$ and $x\in A_2$ are elements of $\mathcal{B}$, it is clear that there is a element $A_3$ of $\mathcal{B}$ such that $x\in A_3\subseteq A_1 \cap A_2$, since the intersection of two elements of $\mathcal{B}$ in this case is itself an element of $\mathcal{B}$. So $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis.