# Topological space inducing a space such that it is a subspace of that space?

Tags: general-topology

If $\;Y\subseteq X^2$ and $\tau$ is any topology on $Y$, is it possible to induce topologies in $X$ from $\tau$?

Are there ways to define topologies on $X$ from $\tau$ so that $(Y,\tau)$ become a subspace of the product space?

---

**Erroneous**
Define $\tau_1,\;\tau_2$ on $X$ by the two functions $p_k:Y\to X$ defined as $p_k(x_1,x_2)=x_k$:

1. Given $A\subseteq X,\;x\in\bar A\iff   
       p_k^{-1}(x)\subseteq\overline{p_k^{-1}(A)}, \;k=1,2$.
   (NOT TRU! WILL REPAIR OR DELETE)

I used [this unauthorized method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544931/a-base-for-a-topology/938508#938508) to prove 1: any relation 
$\propto\,\subseteq X\times \mathcal P(X)$ that extends $'\!\!\in'$ in the way that,

1. $x\in M\Rightarrow x\propto M$
2. $\neg\exists x\in X:x\propto\emptyset$
3. $x\propto A \subseteq B \Rightarrow x\propto B$
4. $x\propto A\cup B\Rightarrow x\propto A \vee x\propto B$

defines a closure operation on subsets of $X$ by 
$x\in \overline M \Leftrightarrow x\propto M$,

Comment: Does your closure operator really define a topology? I fail to see that it is compatible with finite unions ($\overline{A \cup B} = \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$).

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch: I can't be too sure, but I used the method I have included in the Q.

Comment: It is correct, that if 1. to 4. are satisfied this method gives you a closure operator. However, I believe that in your case the 4th property is not satisfied, because you could have $p_k^{-1}(x) \subseteq \overline{p_k^{-1}(A)} \cup \overline{p_k^{-1}(B)}$ but neither $p_k^{-1}(x) \subseteq \overline{p_k^{-1}(A)}$ nor $p_k^{-1}(x) \subseteq \overline{p_k^{-1}(B)}$.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch: I was unlucky when trying to think here - of course you are right. I will later try to repair, somehow, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X=\{0,1\}$, and let $Y=X\times X$. Let

$$\mathscr{B}=\big\{\{\langle 0,0\rangle\},\{\langle 1,0\rangle\},X\times\{1\}\big\}\;,$$

and let $\tau$ be the topology on $Y$ generated by the base $\mathscr{B}$.

Suppose that there topologies $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ on $X$ such that $Y$ is the product topology on $X\times X$ generated by $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$; the projection map $\pi_1$ to the first coordinate must be be continuous and open. Since $\pi_1^{-1}[\{0\}]$ and $\pi_1^{-1}[\{1\}]$ are not open in $Y$, continuity of $\pi_1$ implies that $\{0\},\{1\}\notin\tau_1$ and hence that $\tau_1=\{\varnothing,X\}$, the indiscrete topology on $X$. On the other hand, the fact that $\pi_1$ is open implies that $\{0\}=\pi_1[\{\langle 0,0\rangle\}]$ and $\{1\}=\pi_1[\{\langle 1,0\rangle\}]$ are open in $\langle X,\tau_1\rangle$ and hence that $\tau_1$ is the discrete topology $\wp(X)$ on $X$. This contradiction shows that no such topologies $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ exist: $Y$ is not (a subspace of) any product topology on $X\times X$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if $X$ is a set, $Y$ a topological space and $f : Y \rightarrow X$ is a function, then we can define $\tau_{f} = \{U \subseteq X \:|\: f^{-1}(U) \in \tau_Y\}$ where $\tau_Y$ is the topology of $Y$. Then $\tau_f$ is a topology of $X$, in fact, it is the finest topology for which $f$ is continuous.

In your situation, if $Y \subseteq X^2$ is endowed with a topology $\tau_Y$, let $p_k : Y \rightarrow X$ be the restrictions of the two projections of $X^2$ to $X$. Then $\tau_{p_k}$ gives a topology on $X$ for which $p_k$ is continuous. Hence the inclusion map $p_1 \times p_2 : Y \rightarrow X^2$ is continuous when $X^2$ is equipped with the product topology $\tau_{p_1} \times \tau_{p_2}$ and so $Y$ is a subspace. Note also that this product topology is the same as the topology $\tau_{p_1 \times p_2}$, so a subset of $X^2$  is open in this topology if and only if the intersection of this set with $Y$ is open in $Y$. This topology is the finest topology such that $Y$ is a subspace of $X^2$.

Comment: This does not work: see the example in my answer. In particular, $Y$ can have a finer topology than this product topology.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott : You are absolutely right, I did not take into account that inclusion not only has to be continuous but open, too.